# Building a Min Heap

Tags: sorting, heap, min

This might seem kind of a dumb question but I've been trying for hours now but just can't get it. I have to construct a Min Heap using the elements:

```
120 140 40 50 80 70 60 90 20 100
```

In the first method I adjusted the position of the element of the heap the moment it was introduced, something like pushing it up until an element smaller than itself is encountered. The result was:

```
20 40 60 50 80 120 70 140 90 100
```

This is also the method an online heap visualizer used.

In the second method, I ran a Min-Heapify algorithm recursively on each node, starting from n/2 down to 1, where each node that had a child smaller than it (smaller of the two if both are smaller) exchanged itself with the child. The result was:

```
20 50 40 90 80 70 60 120 140 100
```

When you look at it, it seems to be fulfilling the requirements of a min heap of having the smallest element at the node and each element is smaller than its children. My question is that how come am I getting two different min heaps for a given sequence of numbers, and is it possible for both to be valid? (I tried googling that too with no success).
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid. Heaps don't guarantee a particular structure for a particular set of elements; they only guarantee the rules you mentioned (highest priority element at the root, all elements higher priority than their descendants). The exact structure will vary depending on the order of operations.